# Get config in Routes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to prefix all my routes with a value from config but I am having trouble getting the value from the config file:

```
Config::get('custom.routes.prefix');
```

The above gets null even though the value is set in the config file:

```
//config/custom.php

'routes' =>  => [
   'prefix' => 'whatever',
],
```

How can I get access to config in routes.php?

### Edit

Please note this is not how a question about how to prefix routes, it's how to prefix them with a value from config.

Comment: I don't think you can access `config()` in routes, but you can access `env()`, so why not add `ROUTE_PREFIX=whatever` to your `.env` file and access `Route::group(["prefix" => env("ROUTE_PREFIX")] , ...` EDIT: After testing, it seems you can use `config()` in routes, so it must be another issue.

Comment: Could you show me an example of your route file with it working? Thanks!

Comment: `Route::get("/".env("APP_ENV"), function(){ dd(config("app.env")); });`, then navigating to `/local` returns `"local"`. Works the same if you switch the positions of `env()` and `config()`

Comment: Thanks - was a problem with my config file.

Comment: No problem, glad you figured it out!

Comment: @TimLewis is incorrect. You can retrieve all of your configuration values normally through the facade, or the `config()` helper function inside your `routes.php` file. EDIT, saw your edit @TimLewis. Disregard comment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just store the **route name** in the config file, like;

`return [
    'route' => 'admin.index',
]`

Then use it with the *route helper*. For example...

`<a href="{!! route(config('yourConfig.route')) !!}">Admin</a>`

Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-access-route-method-in-config-file/replies/126295

Answer (score -1):

Your `config/custom.php` file:

```
'routes' => [

    'prefix' => 'home',

],
```

Your `app/Http/routes.php` file:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => config('custom.routes.prefix')], function () {

    // This route will be prefix with your configured prefix.

    Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');

});
```

Comment: Does not work, when I list the routes the value is blank, meaning their is no prefix.

Comment: No, it should work. Like you stated in your comment `Thanks - was a problem with my config file`. You can access all of your configurations values in your `routes.php` file. If you can't, then something else is going on.